# crear una tabla que ocupe 2 columnas

Tags: html, html-tabla

estoy intentando crear una tabla que ocupe 2 columnas en un solo campo de una tabla. hasta ahora tengo lo siguiente:

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="center">Comprador</td>
                <td class="center" colspan="2">Sucursal 1</td>
                <td class="center" colspan="2">Sucursal 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td class="center">Proveedores</td>
               <td class="center">Productos</td>
               <td class="center">Proveedores</td>
               <td class="center">Productos</td>
            </tr>
      </thead>
  </table>
```

[image: Ejemplo de como se ve actualmente]

pero "Comprador" se muestra en la primera fila, no en las dos. deseo que se muestre en las dos.

Alguna idea de como realizar esto?
Deseo que se vea así: (edité la imagen para mostrarlo)
[image: Resultado esperado]

Comment: No entiendo, talvez deberias poner una imagen de lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: hice una edición de mi post, a ver si es más claro de esta manera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí un ejemplo de lo que necesitas:

```html
<table border="1">
  <col>
  <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
  <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Comprador</td>
    <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">Sucursal 1</th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">Sucursal 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Proveedores</th>
    <th scope="col">Productos</th>
    <th scope="col">Proveedores</th>
    <th scope="col">Prodcutos</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Puedes revisar en la siguiente página sobre [este tema](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/irregular/):

Answer (score 2):

Debe usar la propiedad rowspan de la etiqueta td del comprador

```
<td class="center" rowspan="2">Comprador</td>
```